# Paypal Sandbox Test Account login?

Tags: paypal

Unable to login with Test Account

Repro:

1) Created Test Account on "developer.paypal.com".

2) On "Paypal.com" created a button and added it to my site.

3) Changed the button code to include sandbox as in:

```
<form action="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
```

4) Setup Instant Payment Notification (IPN) on paypal.com

5) On "developer.paypal.com" logged into the "Enter Sandbox Test Site".

6) Opening my site in a new tab in the same browser.

Note: IPN - if you have more than one site, it is up to you how to handle this, no link between site and IPN, right?

```
The Problem I am getting is this - what is wrong?

PayPal cannot process this transaction because of a problem with the seller's website. Please contact the seller directly to resolve this problem.
```

Notes:

1. I works if I am removing "sandbox" from the form action?
2. At some point it gave me a site, saying loging to developer.paypal.com or something.

After two days, 10 hours of... you know trying and trying, I am not in a happy place anymore.
Thanks in advance
Regards

Comment: Please include all relevant code.

Comment: What do you mean - there is no code apart from the button html tag?

Comment: This looks like a solution. I will test it and get back: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8683483/how-do-i-test-paypal-subscription-buttons-with-sandbox

Comment: I found my answer here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8683483/how-do-i-test-paypal-subscription-buttons-with-sandbox

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok, I found the solution - I totally missed the Sandbox setup. Understanding the test environment - having a seller and a buyer within developer.paypal.com.

So if you are frustrated out there - it actually works really well.

Regards
Christian